# Timed While Loop

Tags: loops, python-3.x, input, timer, while-loop

I am new to Python and I need some help with something I am trying to do. I am running on Python 3. I need to be able to put input in for the timer which I set to 20 seconds, and for the line "Enter a word using..." to reappear after each time I put input, and then end the loop when the timer is up, and no longer accept input. Sorry if my stardards of coding are awful, I am new to Python.

```
Arbitrary = False    
while time.time() - start < timeOut:
    Arbitrary = True    
    if Arbitrary == True :
        Giveword = input("%s %10s%s" %("Enter a word using ", toPrint,": "))
break
print("Time's Up!")
```

Comment: On first glance, without having tried it, your code looks good. (Apart from that entirely poitless `if Arbitrary == True :` check that will always be true) Is it not working? If so, what is the problem? Do you want to save the words in a list? Or do you want to abort the current input when the time is up?

Comment: I'd actually like to be able to do both, save entries in a list as well as stop enabling input once the time is up...I may have omitted the part about putting the input into a list, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more simple code which gives the words in a list.

```
words = []
while time.time() - start < timeOut:
    Giveword = input("%s %10s%s" %("Enter a word using ", toPrint,": "))
    words.append(Giveword)
print("Time's Up!")
print("Here are your words:", words)
```

Is this what you needed? If not please clarify the question.

Comment: `lists()` should be `list()` or better just `[]`. Also, that format string can be simplified to `"Enter a word using %10s:" % toPrint`

Comment: Please cut out the salutations.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, works great!! Thank you all so much